# Can I use SharedPreferences (and PreferenceFragment) for per-account settings?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm using AccountManager, after implementing my own Authenticator and SyncAdapter. So I'm storing the users's username and password in the Account. I'd like to store other settings for each user, such as how many items the SyncAdapter should cache locally.

I'm afraid I'll have to use AccountManager.setUserData() and AccountManager.getUserData() instead of SharedPreferences. But I like the convenience of PreferenceFragment and its  XML definition. Is there no way to associate SharedPreferences with an Account and let PreferenceFragment deal with the account-specific SharedPreferences?